# Why the writer did not put an article in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article, determiners

> - "I will take him as *ward*, if you wish"

Why the writer didn't use an article before ***ward***?

Answer (score 3):

**ward** is a *role*, broadly conceived. Guardian: ward, mentor : protege, leader: follower, etc.  Articles are not used when the noun refers to the role.

> He was **the** 40th president of the country. <sup>specific instance</sup>
>
> He was elected president. <sup>elected to the role/position</sup>
>
> He was appointed guardian to the child.
>
> He took the child on as ward.

Note the use of the preposition **as**.  It signals a role.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got confused because when I looked at the oxford dictionary, I didn't see if this word is countable or uncountable. Besides, there are other contexts where this word, ward, is used as countable, so they have put article, a, before.

Comment: Whether the noun is countable or non-count is not the only factor. These nouns are countable (wards, presidents). But when referring to the *role* no article is used.    The preposition **as** is usually a good clue that the role is being referred to.

Comment: So, if you put ***a*** before the word. Would something change? Such as: he worked as ***a*** teacher or as teacher?

Comment: @BavyanYaldo, that's an interesting example.  With an article, like "a", it isn't really a role, it's a specific position.  With just "as", it would be in the generic role of a teacher (which would have nothing to do with qualifications for teaching).  So maybe a sentence like, "A group of parents set up a home school, with Johnny's mother as teacher."  However, "He worked as teacher" would imply to most readers that you are talking about a specific occupation or position, so it would sound wrong.

Comment: @BanyanYaldo: *He worked as **a** teacher* means his occupation was teacher. It was a job he held.  But this would be different: *Ms Jones, have you come before the school  board today **as teacher or basketball coach**?*  There, the questioner wants to know what role or capacity the person is acting in.

Comment: @fixer1234 so if we take the example that mentioned above "he was elected president. Here, is president a specific position or general?

Comment: @BavyanYaldo, "President" is a specific position, but it functions as more of a role that is played by the person holding the office at the time.  It doesn't have a job description as much as powers, responsibilities, and constraints that the office holder is temporarily endowed with to allow acting in that capacity.   "He was elected president" would refer to acting in the role or capacity of president.

Answer (score 2):

A circumstance when "**ward**" *does* take an article is

> He became **a** ward of the state.
>   *He went into foster care*.

"**Ward**" is one of those legal terms which can get used, in what I term, a "flat" way, without articles.

"Ward", "guardian" "power of attorney" are examples.

> As **guardian** your written permission is necessary...
>   He has **power of attorney** over all matters...