# Omitting the indefinite article before occupations

Tags: indefinite-article

From what I understand, one can omit the indefinite article when referring to unique titles or roles/professions, e.g. “He's captain of the local football team”.

With less unique roles, I have conflicting intuitions about it, possibly stemming from other languages, e.g.

“He is singer for the New York opera.”
“She is cook in a very famous restaurant.”

I know that “is a” would definitely be right here, but can the article also be omitted?

Comment: No, this would be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D.Trump was elected president or "a" president.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134292/d-trump-was-elected-president-or-a-president) Wherein the top-rated answer cites Longman's Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English, with *When a predicative noun phrase names a unique role or job, either a zero article or **the** is used.* Giving as one of the example usages: ***She is chef, owner, and head dishwasher***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, the example in the paragraph you quoted explains where my (vague) intuition comes from.